# SpringBoot Oracle DataSource URL How does it work?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, datasource

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://springframework.guru/using-h2-and-oracle-with-spring-boot/) on using oracle and h2 with SpringBoot. I've tried configuring the *spring.datasource.url* in *application-oracle.properties* to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8443 for my own system but the network adapter cannot establish the connection. Any ideas?

Comment: The default port for oracle is 1521 and the URL is also missing the service name. For details see the Oracle JDBC manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#JJDBC08200

Comment: specify some code and what error you get